# gitlab installation failing on debian 9.6

Tags: debian, ruby-on-rails, ruby, gitlab, rubygems

I'm having a issue on Debian 9.6. When installing gitlab an error is returned:

```
Setting up gitlab (8.13.11+dfsg1-8+deb9u3) ...
Creating/updating gitlab user account...
Making gitlab owner of /var/lib/gitlab...
Could not find gem 'rails (~> 4.2, >= 4.2.7.1)' in any of the gem sources listed
in your Gemfile.
dpkg: error processing package gitlab (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gitlab
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have checked and I have installed both the ruby and the ruby-rails package on the server.

I have unpacked the deb file and traced down the issue to this part in the postintall script:

```
if ! runuser -u ${gitlab_user} -- sh -c 'bundle --local --quiet'; then
  if [ "$1" = "triggered" ]; then
    # probably triggered in the middle of an system upgrade; ignore failure
    # but abort here
    echo "#########################################################################"
    echo "# Failed to detect gitlab dependencies; if you are in the middle of an #"
    echo "# upgrade, this is probably fine, there will be another attempt later.  #"
    echo "#                                                                       #"
    echo "# If you are NOT in the middle of an upgrade, there is probably a real  #"
    echo "# issue. Please report a bug.                                           #"
    echo "#########################################################################"
    exit 0
  else
    # something is really broken
    exit 1
  fi  
fi
```

Basically the error mentioned in the question is thrown by the following command: `runuser -u ${gitlab_user} -- sh -c 'bundle --local --quiet'`

Any suggestion on what could cause this?

Comment: What is the version of ruby-rails you have installed?

Comment: ruby-rails is already the newest version (2:4.2.7.1-1). From apt. Thanks

Comment: I think you should use command like `gem install rails -v 4.2.7.1` but `gem` can't find any source of this version.